# PayPal auto-return script always called twice

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently working on payments using PayPal. Everything was running smoothly until recently. I have a subscription button. I've set the return URL to handle getting data from the transaction then mailing it to the user. All the data I needed are being retrieved successfully, however, the problem is my functions runs twice upon return. I get the emails I'm supposed to receive twice. This was working fine a couple of weeks back so now I'm wondering what happened why it suddenly got this bug.

I've read here : [Paypal adaptive payment return url is calling twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337604/paypal-adaptive-payment-return-url-is-calling-twice) that it could be because I tapped the 'click here' button even tho it hasn't been 10 seconds yet. I already tried clicking and not clicking it but I still get the same result.

I've also read that this could be because it gets called upon payment and then for the start of the subscription. Any idea how I could handle this?

```
$pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; // Change to www.sandbox.paypal.com to test against sandbox
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "my_token_from_paypal";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
//if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(!$res){
    //HTTP ERROR
}else{
     // parse the data
    $lines = explode("\n", trim($res));
    $keyarray = array();
    if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) 
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
            $temp = explode("=", $lines[$i],2);
            $keyarray[urldecode($temp[0])] = urldecode($temp[1]);
         }

         // code for mail handling
    }
    else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
        echo 'there has been an error';
    }
}
```

Comment: You must share your code.

Comment: I'm using the usual code for handling PDT. Please see edit.

Comment: Do you using jquery or ajax when call server code?

Comment: I am using PHP. I tried changing the button to Buy Now and the mail doesnt duplicate. I've read that for Subscription button, it gets called once after the payment and once again for the start of the subscription. I tried logging the transaction ID and sure enough, I get two different IDs on each email.